# C# Winform Control for comments

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, comments, controls

Is there any Winform control available which can help create comment section as seen in the example below?

Or if there is any other method through which current Visual Studio controls can  be used to create something similar?

[image: Example]

Comment: There is nothing like that. You have to build a user control, and add it in `FlowLayoutPanel` which could bring close to what you see there. If you use wpf, you can use ListBox with data templates.

Comment: Your screenshot displays a browser.  Yes, HTML is rather good at displaying a mix of images and a variety of text styles.  A ListView with View = Tile is only a weak approximation.  RichTextBox can technically do it, controlling the images is a pita.  A UserControl is going to quickly bog down your UI when you display a lot of them.  So, maybe you should just use a WebBrowser.

Comment: @HansPassant I need it in a Windows application don't want to run as WebBrowser. What do you suggest?

Comment: WebBrowser is a standard control you find back in the toolbox.  It works on Windows.  Click and drag it to put one on your form.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok thanks, will have a look. Don't really know much about,  it would be nice if you can point me towards some examples.

Comment: It would be nice if you spent more time learning the tool and get a feel for what is practical and what is not.  You can do that all by yourself without anybody's help.

Comment: Hey I just saw some tutorials on web browser control. If I understand correctly it is a way to access already created webpages and link them to your C# app. If that is the case I need to have a webpage as a prerequisite right?